# Cargar el archivo context

Tags: java, spring-mvc

tengo un proyecto web con Spring y en WEB-INF guardo el archivo **web.xml** y el **spring_mvc_servlet.xml**, como hago para acceder al segundo xml desde una clase Java de la forma,

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_mvc_servlet.xml");
```

pues no lo encuentra.

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si se encuentra el archivo dentro de `/WEB-INF/` puedes cargarlo de esta forma, haciendo referencia al directorio que lo contiene:

```
String path = "/WEB-INF/spring_mvc_servlet.xml";
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path);
```

o puedes usar el prefijo "`classpath*:`"

```
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:spring_mvc_servlet.xml");
```